# event.keycode vs event.which

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I fell foul of a Firefox `keydown` behavior in that pressing the enter key (indeed any key) without having focus on a specific field will NOT trigger a `keydown` event it will only trigger a `keypress event.

This could be very confusing as the `keydown` and `keyup` event use JavaScript key codes whereas `keypress` uses ASCII codes. Fortunately 13 (enter/return) is common to both.

Is there any known reason why Firefox using `keypress` in this circumstance? What is the benefit?

Once this was established IE8 threw up a silly in that it does not permit `preventDefault` demanding instead `returnValue = false` the following snippet from another Stack Overflow post has proved very useful:

```
event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
```

During the search to resolve these issues I have been consistently confused by `event.keycode` vs `event.which`. Namely am I doing wrong using a switch statement similar to:

```
$("#class_Name").bind("keydown", function(event){
    // do not test input if field controls used
    switch(event.which){
       case 13:
       //enter key 
       event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
       break;
     }
```

Is the following better, if so why?

```
$("body").keypress(function(event){
     // stop inadvertant form submission
     if (event.keycode == "13"){
       event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
     }
});
```

I would just like to know so that I know which is best to apply.

Comment: You do know that jQuery normalizes the differences between browsers? In jQuery, `event.which` is expected to be consistent across browsers. Also, jQuery's `event.preventDefsult();` will also work in OldIE.

Comment: @Rob W, Hi Rob yes indeed I was aware of this. The online jquery documentation documents the use of event.which which I have used. Many posts show herein use keycode not which. Hence the question. I understand that event.preventDefsult(); should work everywhere.

Comment: Wondering if we can get an update on this for relevant browsers in 2016?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some browsers use `keyCode` and others use `which`. But with jQuery this is *normalized* so you don't have to think about that. You can just choose the one you prefer.

Comment: only for the case that the event was generated by jquery itself. Catching a native events and normalizing them is not possible

Answer (score 9):

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568727/javascript-jquery-keypress-for-keyboard-navigation-event-which-doesnt-work/21701725#comment3741856_3568784) jQuery can be unreliable and [this page](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) says:

`event.which` is undefined in IE<9 on `keydown` and `keyup`.

`event.keyCode` is 0 in Gecko (Seamonkey, Firefox) on `keypress` for keys that return a character.

`event.charCode` is only supported on keydown and keyup by Internet Explorer (Mac).

[Try it on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3QM8t/1/)

Comment: This helped for me. It should be the accepted answer. I am using the following line to normalize these properties:

`var code = event.which || event.keyCode || event.charCode;`

This grabs whichever field is not null or 0. If they are all zero, then it returns 0.