# how do i add keyboard shortcut enter to jquery to do list

Tags: jquery

I'm new to  jquery and I'm making my first project which is a basic to do list. Im trying to make it work when someone presses enter but for some reason nothing is happening.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn2").click(
    function() {
      var toAdd = $("#listItem").val();
      $("ol").append("<li>" + toAdd + "</li>");
    });
});

$(document).on('dblclick', 'li', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('strike').fadeOut('slow');
});

$('#listItem').keypress(function(event) {
      var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
      if (keycode == '13') {
        var toAdd = $("#listItem").val();



        $("ol").append("<li>" + toAdd + "</li>");
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form name="toDoList">
  <input type="text" id="listItem" name="ListItem" />
</form>
<ol>
</ol>
<button id="btn2">Add something</button>
<p>something</p>
<p>ldldl</p>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [mcve] - I create a snippet for you. As you can see when pressing TIDY it is not complete. Also look at the console when clicking. You also had invalid HTML with html in the head and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- added ALL the event handling to the load event
- closed the brackets
- removed ) from if
- added class
- event.which is normalised by jQuery

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    var toAdd = $("#listItem").val();
    $("ol").append("<li>" + toAdd + "</li>");
  });
  $("#listItem").keypress(function(e) {
    var keycode = e.which;
    if (keycode == '13') {
      var toAdd = $("#listItem").val();
      $("ol").append("<li>" + toAdd + "</li>");
    }
  });
});

$(document).on('dblclick', 'li', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('strike').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

```css
.strike { text-decoration:line-through}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form name="toDoList">
  <input type="text" id="listItem" name="ListItem" />
</form>
<ol>
</ol>
<button id="btn2">Add something</button>
<p>something</p>
<p>ldldl</p>
```

Comment: what does event.which mean

Comment: Some browsers use keycode, some which. but jQuery normalises it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172646/event-keycode-vs-event-which