# Triggering Ctrl S or Ctrl P via a button

Tags: jquery, triggers, key, keypress, ctrl

Ok now I am aware that you can listen to keypresses (keydowns keyups etc...) but I would like to TRIGGER a keypress.  Like as if the user presses <kbd>CTRL+S</kbd> to save.

Short question is, is it possible to use Jquery to trigger 2 key presses at the same time? I have been trying to look this up but all the stuff I found was talking about capturing key presses and not triggering them especially 2 key presses at the same time.

Any ideas how this can be accomplished? If you could lead me to the right track it would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: capture key press without placing an input element on the page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878983/javascript-capture-key-press-without-placing-an-input-element-on-the-page)

Comment: @Marc: You're misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Is this even cross browser, let alone cross OS compatible? For instance Ctrl+S will work in Windows, but it most certainly will not work in Mac. Also, what happens if someone has bound their keys differently?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to trigger your own handler code, you should just put that code in a separate function and call the function normally.

If you want to trigger the browser's default functionality, you should give up; that is impossible for security reasons.  (Although you may be interested in `window.print()`)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you can trigger the key presses but perhaps if you explain what you are specifically trying to achieve you might be able to find a solution?

For example, if you want to trigger <kbd>ctrl-p</kbd> to bring up the print dialog you can do this using `window.print();`

If you want to trigger actions in your own code then you can just call the code directly rather than triggering the key press.

I don't think there is any way to trigger a file | save as (<kbd>ctrl-s</kbd>) by using JavaScript though.