# Saving current page or triggering ctrl+s combination on button or href tags chrome jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, save

Can I save current page from browser (I don't have it in server), if not, how can I trigger ctrl+s combination when I press button or href? Im repeating: I DON'T HAVE PAGE ON SERVER, so i cant do something like this: `<a href="downloads/page.html" download>Download page</a>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Triggering Ctrl S or Ctrl P via a button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808650/triggering-ctrl-s-or-ctrl-p-via-a-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this  .simply add current url in this `a`

```js
$('a').attr('href',window.location.href)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" download>Download page</a>.
```