# Jquery dialog submit form by Enter Key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want submit form for Jquery dialog by pressing enter key.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Pin Notification Form -->
<div id="pin-dialog-form" title="Verification Pin">
   <div id="agent_pin_container">
      <input type="password" name="verification_pin" id="verification_pin"
      value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Verification Pin" />
</div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$( "#pin-dialog-form" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
height: 200,
width: 300,
modal: true,
buttons: {
    "Submit": function() {
        // PROCESS
    },
    Cancel: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
},
close: function() {
    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
}
});
```

Now, I can not use this type of code in here, `if (e.keyCode == 13) {`. Because, the form is submitted by modal window itself. on the other hand I can not use this,

```
open: function() {
  $(this).parents('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:eq(0)').focus(); 
}
```

because, I need to enter PIN first then focus on submit button.
Is there any other way to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submitting a form on 'Enter' with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699065/submitting-a-form-on-enter-with-jquery)

Comment: I already mention those scenario in my question. It's not duplicate of that question.

Comment: You should combine it with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878983/capture-key-press-without-placing-an-input-element-on-the-page then

Comment: @LucaB.: Can you please combine those 2 in here. I don't know how to do that. If you can then that would be a great help. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As per comments you should be able to grab keypress document-wide using:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    // CODE TO SUBMIT THE FORM either AJAX or *form*.submit()
    // CODE TO CLOSE THE MODAL
  }
});
```

sources:

[Submitting a form on 'Enter' with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699065/submitting-a-form-on-enter-with-jquery)

[Capture key press without placing an input element on the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878983/capture-key-press-without-placing-an-input-element-on-the-page)