# How can I keep the browser from intercepting and interpreting keys

Tags: javascript, html

I want keystrokes to trigger some javascript code. I found [Capture key press without placing an input element on the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2878983) and it works, except that the browser gets those keystrokes, too, and does a lot of unwanted things, for example, it starts "Quick Find" and takes the focus away.

So how can I tell the browser to ignore a range of keys for a specific window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually by using `return false` in the keydown event handler would be sufficient to prevent default browser behaviour. Eg:

```
window.onkeydown = function(event){
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    if (keyCode == 13) {    //prevent enter key from being detected
        return false;
    }
}
```

Reference for key codes: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

Comment: It works! And +1 for the link to the key codes. But can you please explain what that return false exactly does? It doesn't stop the event bubbling further up?

Comment: Hm, it worked the first few tries, but now the Quick Find opens again. Confusing. Will have to experiment for a while.

Comment: return false will usually be an indicator to browsers to ignore that event, however to be safe you can add event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation() if they exist

Comment: Looks like it works for keydown, but not keyup, but what have I seen the first time? Confusing.

Comment: It should be possible to do this window.onkeydown = window.onkeyup = function(event)...

Comment: Ouch, I see what happened. When using onkeyup the onkeydown event has already escaped to the browser! No with "onkeydown="return false;" onkeyup="event.preventDef..." it works.