# Why isn't the Javascript addEventListener doing anything?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to write a script that moves the orange box around inside the blue box using the arrow keys and Javascript eventlistener. When I run the page, nothing happens. I've tried poking around in the console, but it isn't giving me any output at all. I'm sure I'm missing something small but I can't for the life of me figure it out. Any suggestions would be great!

```js
var orange = document.getElementById("orange");
orange.addEventListener("onkeydown", move, false);
function move(e);
       
e = e || window.event;
    
   if(e.keyCode == '38'){ //up
     if(parseInt(orange.style.top) > '0'){
      orange.style.top = parseInt(orange.style.top) - 5;
     }
   } else if (e.keyCode == '40'){ //down
     if(parseInt(orange.style.top) < '425'){
      orange.style.top = parseInt(orange.style.top) + 5;
     }
   } else if (e.keyCode == '37'){ //left
     if(parseInt(orange.style.top) > '0'){
      orange.style.left = parseInt(orange.style.left) - 5;
     }
   } else if (e.keyCode == '39') { //right
     if(parseInt(orange.style.left) < '425') {
      orange.style.left = parseInt(orange.style.left) + 5;
     }    
   }
}
```

```css
#blue{
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px
}
#orange{
    background-color: orange;
    position: absolute;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
};
```

```html
 <div id="blue">
     <div id ="orange" style="left: 30px; top:30px;"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: FYI, `e = e || window.event;` is unnecessary. You're using a fix that doesn't make sense inside an `addEventListener` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple problems:

1) The event is `keydown` not `onkeydown` (unless you are adding directly to the object: (e.g. `orange.onkeydown`)

2) Top is measured in pixels, not just an integer - you need to add `+ 'px'` to your top changes: `orange.style.top = parseInt(orange.style.top) + 5 + 'px'`

Other notes:

- Might work better to have the event listener on window as it will have focus, idk though - didn't test that.
- `e.keyCode` is a Number, not a String
- as @bmceldowney mentioned, you have a syntax error in your function declaration

Working version of your code: https://jsfiddle.net/kkhkL065/

Comment: Yes. A div is unlikely to have focus so it won't receive a keydown event. UI elements like input and textareas can receive keydown events. Listening on document or window i preferred because the event would bubble up anyway regardless of what part of the page have focus.

Comment: Thanks! I made the changes you and @slebetman suggested and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You should be getting a syntax error in your console because you're not declaring your `move` function correctly.

```
function move(e);

    e = e || window.event;
```

should look like this:

```
function move(e) {

        e = e || window.event;
```

Comment: Ok, I changed it but it didn't make a difference

Comment: That is only part of it, you can't associate it to that div if the key press is not associated with it. Here is a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878983/capture-key-press-without-placing-an-input-element-on-the-page

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown) by Mozilla,
the possible targets of the **keydown** event (not **onkeydown** as erroneously written in your code) are

> Focused element processing the key event, root element if no suitable
>   input element focused

So basically only **input** (`<input>` and `<textarea>`) or **root elements**  (document or window) can process the event.

Modify your code like this:

```
var orange = document.getElementById("orange");
var move = function(e){
    orange.classList.add("red");
}
window.addEventListener("keydown", move, false);
```

Here's a link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nbj0Lujw/

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I've never heard of JSFiddle, looks like it'll be really helpful!

Comment: It's really helpful when you need to test something by isolating it from the rest of your codebase :) try codepen.io too ;)