# How to add another key to preform a browser default?

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting to add another key to preform a browser default, for example

pressing the shift key will do the same as pressing the tab key

I'm not trying to prevent the tab key from doing anything I just want another key to do the same.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I do know how to do what I want to achieve how ever it requires some code, and I did not whether or not there was a really simple way of doing such as just listening for a keypress than running "the tab key action".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture key press without placing an input element on the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878983/capture-key-press-without-placing-an-input-element-on-the-page)